# Client authorization tab deleted from keycloak panel?

Tags: keycloak

As I see in this link https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_overview , 
there should be an authorization tab in client like below image : 
[image: keycloak.org documentation screenshot]

but I couldn't find that in keycloak panel as you can see in below image:

[image: My keycloak panel screenshot]

ps : I use this image for using keycloak on docker :    `image: jboss/keycloak`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your client is `public`. Set: `Access Type: confidential`, then enable `Authorization Enabled` and Save. Refresh page and double check these configured values.